# Basic theorem for solvable groups not true for nilpotent groups - counterexample.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, solvable-groups, quotient-group, nilpotent-groups

it's my first question on MathStackExchange so please be tolerant.

Let H be a normal subgroup of group G. If H and G/H are both solvable, then G is solvable. But H nilpotent and G/H nilpotent doesn't follow that G nilpotent. I found that once but there was no counterexample there and I can't find it myself. It would be nice, if someone reading that question would make it clear.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dihedral group $D_3$ is a split extension of the cyclic group $C_3$ by the cyclic group $C_2$. However, $D_3\cong S_3$ is not nilpotent since we have $Z(D_3)=1$ and a finite nilpotent group has a nontrivial center. So we have a counterexample, with $H=C_3$, $G=D_3$.